# How can I limit the number of request which can be processed in Spring webflux (netty webserver)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty

I want something equivalent to setting this property in tomcat. which will set the number of threads in thread pool to 100 so the maximum number of request that can be processed concurrently is 100 request.

```
server.tomcat.maxthread=100
```

but in webflux (netty webserver) I could not find the configuration property that will limit the request.

this is what I have tried so far

1 - define a custom bean for `ReactiveWebServerFactory`. I create 2 API endpoints for testing the first one is **blocking IO** second one is not, **but it can only process one request at a time another request had to wait until the first one is finish** eventhough it **should** runs on difference thread.

```
@Bean
public ReactiveWebServerFactory reactiveWebServerFactory() {
        NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
        factory.addServerCustomizers(builder -> builder.runOn(new NioEventLoopGroup(2)));

        return factory;
}
```

2 - setting this property which I found on the document but It can still process more than 2 requests on difference thread. (I tested the same way as above)

```
server.netty.max-keep-alive-requests=2
```

3 - setting tomcat maxthread to 2, this one has no effect as I expected.

```
server.tomcat.maxthread=2
```

so is it possible to limit the maximum number of request in webflux.

my API for testing

```
@RestController
public class CheckController {

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Mono<Long> something() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("cores " + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        return Mono.just(2L)
                .flatMap(d -> simulateBlockingOperation())
                .log();
    }

    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public Mono<Long> something2() throws InterruptedException {
        return Mono.just(1L)
                .log();
    }

    private Mono<Long> simulateBlockingOperation() {
        System.out.println("Current thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        int x = 0;
        while(x!=1) {}
        return Mono.just(2L);
    }
}
```

update: I temporary solve the issue by creating another thread pool and use .subscribeOn to switch the thread group and limit the number of thread on that thread group instead. but I feel like this is really dirty way of doing it.

```
@RestController
public class CheckController {

    private final Scheduler customThreadPool;

    public CheckController(Scheduler customThreadPool) {
        this.customThreadPool = customThreadPool;
    }
   @Bean
   public Scheduler reactiveRequestThreadPool() {
       return Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(2, 2, "my-custom-thread");
   }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public Mono<Long> something() throws InterruptedException {
        return Mono.just(2L)
                .doOnNext(d -> getCurrentThread())
                .flatMap(d -> simulateBlockingOperation())
                .subscribeOn(customThreadPool)
                .log();
    }

    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public Mono<Long> something2() throws InterruptedException {
        return Mono.just(1L)
                .doOnNext(d -> getCurrentThread())
                .subscribeOn(customThreadPool)
                .log();
    }

    private Mono<Long> simulateBlockingOperation() {
        int x = 0;
        while(x!=1) {}
        return Mono.just(2L);
    }

    private void getCurrentThread() {
        System.out.println("current thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think resilience4j bulkhead with reactive support might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for you. Create a filter that will cover all APIs served by your server. In that filter have a static atomic counter of current requests. Each time a request comes in check the counter if it is not greater then your limit allow the request and increment  the counter. If it is greater than your limit reject the request. Each time request finishes and the response comes back through your filter - decrement the counter.

Comment: great idea but I want it to handle the exceeded requests like how tomcat handles it so instead of rejecting it. It will put the request in the queue, I guess this is how tomcat does, and wait until there's a thread available and start processing it. I wish there's a builtin tool for this

Comment: 1. I understand that you a built in functionality and I don't know if there is one on your server
2. If you do want to implement the functionality yourself than what you do with excessive requests is up to you - you can reject them or implement some waiting functionality